# Flowtype: Exporting class from a factory function

Tags: javascript, flowtype

How do you import a type that is exported from a factory function? (Note, this applies to angularJS factories, so we can't change the way it's working... much) This is what I want to do for example:

Person.js

```
// @flow

export default function personFactory(): Person {
  class Person {
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
      this.name = name;
    }
  }

  return Person;
}
```

Employee.js

```
// @flow

// This won't work since the default export is the factory function
// but bare with me.
import type PersonType from './Person';

employeeFactory.$inject = ['Person'];
export default function employeeFactory(Person: PersonType): Employee {
  class Employee extends Person {
    job: string;     

    constructor(name: string, job: string) {
      super(name);

      this.job = job;
    }
  }

  return Employee;
}
```

Now, is there a way to export the class in the factory function without having to duplicate the type declaration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that classes that are declared inside the factory are not in scope outside of the factory. They are created each time the factory is called, so there really isn't any way to refer to them in general. What we need to do is declare something outside of the Factory carries the type information we care about.

Here are two suggestions

## Using Interfaces

The downside here is that you are re-declaring some of the types. The plus side is that this doesn't have any runtime effect and is pretty clean.

```js
// @flow
export interface IPerson {
  name: string;
}

export default function personFactory(): Class<IPerson> {
  class Person {
    name: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
      this.name = name;
    }
  }

  return Person;
}
```

## Using Classes

The downside here is you are messing with the class hierarchy. The plus side is code reuse

```js
// @flow
class PersonBase {
  name: string;
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
export type Person = typeof PersonBase;

export default function personFactory(): Class<PersonBase> {
  class Person extends PersonBase {}

  return Person;
}
```

Comment: The solution with the interfaces is what I figured I would have to do. It works, just a pain to declare annotations twice. We can't move the class outside of the factory due to dependencies getting injected into the factory. Thanks for the answer!